# Can't launch programs from command line in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, google-chrome, cmd.exe

Since I've reinstalled Windows on my computer, I'm unable to run `cmd /c start chrome`

*EDIT: Not just Chrome. The same thing happens with `start iexplore` or `start winword`. `start cmd` works fine though.*

I get an error

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>
> The parameter is incorrect

[image: Error message received - The paremeter is incorrect]

Google Chrome launches fine when clicking on the relevant shortcut, but many of my development/build tools appear to use the cmd command to start debuggers etc.

Any idea how to fix?

Additionally, if I open a command prompt window, and try run `start chrome`, I get the same error, followed by `Access Denied`
[image: Access denied error]

Comment: How about `start "" chrome`?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT same result. The same command works fine on my other Windows 10 PCs. I'm stumped as to what has gone wrong. Incidentally, `start cmd` works fine, `start firefox` gives the same error

Comment: nice spotting, but no, the issue occurs straight from the windows cmd. I develop with `react` and `react-native` which calls `start chrome` a lot for remote debugging which is why this is so debilitiating

Comment: running as admin doesn't work, nor `start "" chrome`. I've tested running from an elevated command prompt. It feels like there is a corrupt registry setting somewhere but I'm not sure how to track it down. Or it's a bug in the insider build!

Comment: You're probably right.... try to uninstall Chrome, reboot the machine, and then re-install Chrome and see if that resolves it. That's something simple to try to eliminate as a possible solution I suppose. I once had a bug with Chrome on a Windows 10 machine that would only open incognito and never got it figured out so this reminded me of that PC that I'll try to revisit when I'm at that client's site next week. Hopefully you'll find a solution or this will ring a bell for someone else that has something for you .

Comment: the plot thickens... it's not just chrome. `start iexplore` does the same thing, `start winword`, NOT `start cmd` though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this stage, it looks like it's an issue with Windows Insider Preview. Another computer I had available which was working previously stopped working when updated to 17692.rs_prerelease_flt.180625-1624

Lesson learned. Don't update your main machine!